# Symfony Forms: Modify form field options with eventListener on fields with ModelTransformer

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form with a field that has a ModelTransformer. In some cases (relying on the field's data) the field must be disabled (= ignored), because the underlying data is related to another Entity which cannot be linked in the current context. But that is not important for my question.

There are several questions about modifying form options and how to solve that. In short: Inside the event callback listening to `PRE_SET_DATA`, the field must be added again (replacing the existing field) and the old options can be read from the existing field before and readded to the new one. This is not an elegant solution from my point of view, but it is one.

Until there is a Transformer (ModelTransformer oder ViewTransformer) on the existing field, because that transformer will be removed, when the field is added again and cannot be (re)applied from inside the event callback.

In my case, I am lucky because on a disabled field, the ModelTransformer is not needed anymore, so I can do basically that:

```
$builder->add(
    $builder
        ->create('myFieldWithModelTransformer', CheckboxType::class, [])
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function($originalValue) {
                return $originalValue; // or do some transformation
            },
            function($submittedValue) {
                return $submittedValue; // or do some transformation
            }
        ))
);

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
    if (true) { //whatever condition relying on the underlying data
        $event->getForm()->add('myFieldWithModelTransformer', CheckboxType::class, [
            'disabled' => true,
        ]);
        // this removed the ModelTransformer, which also cannot be added in the event context
    }
);
```

But what If I want to change another option like `required` while preserving the ModelTransformer?